# Every Cech cocycle can be represented by a normalised cocycle.

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, sheaf-cohomology, k-theory

Many authors state the conditions of a 1-cocycle $(g_{ij})$ as

- $g_{ii} = 1$,
- $g_{ij} = g_{ji}^{-1}$,
- $g_{ij}g_{ik}^{-1}g_{jk} = 1$.

Note that in this case the first two conditions are implied by the third. If we look instead at a 2-cocycle $(g_{ijk})$, the cocycle condition is
$$
g_{ijk} g_{ij l}^{-1} g_{ikl} g_{jkl}^{-1} = 1.
$$
This condition doesn't for example imply that $g_{iii} = 1$. In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1012.2512) by Karoubi, right before Remark 1.1 he defines a "completely normalised" 2-cocycle to be a 2-cocycle as above such that

- $g_{ijk}=1$ when two of $i,j,k$ are equal, and
- $g_{\sigma(i)\sigma(j)\sigma(k)} = (g_{ijk})^{\varepsilon(\sigma)}$ where $\sigma$ is a permutation of $(i,j,k)$ with signature $\varepsilon(\sigma)$.

These two conditions are similar to the two extra conditions in the definition of a 1-cocycle I stated above except now they aren't a consequence of the Cech 2-cocycle condition. I have seen some authors state similar conditions as being part of the definition of a 2-cocycle, for example page 3 of [these notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9907034) by Hitchin. This confused me until I read Remark 1.1 in the paper I linked:

> Remark 1.1. One can prove (see [21] for instance) that a Cˇech cocycle in any dimension is cohomologous to a completely normalized one. Moreover, if every open subset of X is paracompact, any cohomology class may be represented by a completely normalized Cˇech cocycle.

The paper [21] cited is Karoubi's own paper "Resolutions symetriques" which is unfortunately in French. So my questions are:

1. Is this result (or a similar one) the reason why some can authors add these "normalisation" conditions to the definition of a cocycle?
2. How might one "normalise" a cocycle, that is find a cohomologous cocycle that is normalised? Even just an English reference would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am reading the same paper and have found the same problem. First, note that since $Z$ lives inside the centre of $G$, it is an abelian group and its Cech cohomology is just the usual Cech cohomology for sheaves of abelian groups (although Karoubi uses multiplicative notation). If you check the usual references, for example Hartshorne III.4, he in fact puts a well-ordering on the open covering, defines cochains $g_{U_1,...,U_p}$ just for $U_1<...<U_p$ and then generalizes for general $(U_1,...,U_p)$ precisely by multiplying by $(-1)^\sigma$, so here everything is automatically normalized...

Comment: Thanks Gallego, I appreciate your response. For my purposes I needed normalised 3-cocycles, and I found the answer in Lemma 2.2 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.0679). A similar approach should work at least for all odd degree cocycles.